# How to delete a key within an object in local storage with Javascript and/or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

In local storage I have an object named **`favourites`** and it contains this..

```
"{
    "id3333":{
        "URL":"somewhere.comm/page1/",
        "TITLE":"Page 1 Title",
    },
    "id4444":{
        "URL":"somewhere.comm/page2/",
        "TITLE":"Page 2 Title",
    }
}"
```

How can I delete an object based on its ID (id3333 & id4444 for examples)

I have tried the following along with some other voodoo..

```
localStorage.removeItem('id3333'); // no errors, no removal
localStorage.removeItem('favourites':'id3333'); // SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
localStorage.removeItem('favourites[id3333]'); // no errors, no removal
localStorage.removeItem('id3333', JSON.stringify('id3333')); // no errors, no removal
```

**Also**, I will need to get the key name to delete based on a variable, so like this..

```
var postID = 'id3333';
localStorage.removeItem(postID);
```

or

```
var objectName = 'favourites';
var postID = 'id3333';
localStorage.removeItem(objectName[postID]);
```

Is it possible to remove a nested item directly or do I need to retrieve the full object and then delete the item and then set the object back to local storage again?

The closest I can get to deleting anything directly so far is..

```
localStorage.removeItem('favourites');
```

But that of course removes the entire object.

Comment: You can store only strings in `localStorage`, not objects.  So your only choice is to load the entire string in memory, manipulate it, then save it back.  The JSON methods work perfectly for this, as @epascarello demonstrates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a a single key and you are acting like there are multiple keys

```
var obj = {
    "id3333":{
        "URL":"somewhere.comm/page1/",
        "TITLE":"Page 1 Title",
    },
    "id4444":{
        "URL":"somewhere.comm/page2/",
        "TITLE":"Page 2 Title",
    }
};

window.localStorage.favs = JSON.stringify(obj);  //store object to local storage
console.log("before : ", window.localStorage.favs);  //display it
var favs = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.favs || {});  //read and convert to object
var delKey = "id3333";  //key to remove
if (favs[delKey]) {  //check if key exists
    delete favs[delKey];  //remove the key from object
}
window.localStorage.favs = JSON.stringify(favs);  //save it back
console.log("after : ", window.localStorage.favs);  //display object with item removed
```

Comment: Any reason to check if the key exists?  An error won't be thrown if it doesn't.

Comment: just a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks epascarello. You answered my 'do I need to retrieve the full object', showed me how to target a key for deletion and based that key name on a variable.

Comment: My terminology is terrible. Would id3333 be a key, and URL be a key within that key?

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen Yes. A key/value pair can have for its value another key/value pair.  You could call the inside one a "subkey".

Answer (score 2):

With `localStorage.removeItem` you can only remove top level keys, i.e. keys directly on `localStorage`.

Because `id3333` is on `localStorage.favourites` you cannot remove it using `localStorage.removeItem`.

Instead try `delete localStorage.favourties['id3333']`

Answer (score 1):

Simple, actually: you just `delete` it.  :)

```
x = {
    "id3333":{
        "URL":"somewhere.comm/page1/",
        "TITLE":"Page 1 Title",
    },
    "id4444":{
        "URL":"somewhere.comm/page2/",
        "TITLE":"Page 2 Title",
    }
};
console.log(x);
delete x.id3333;
console.log(x);
```

`delete` does what you're looking for.  You could also do something like `delete x.id3333.TITLE` if you were so inclined.  Note also that `delete` returns `true` if successful and `false` if not.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the reply. `delete x.id3333.TITLE` is good to know and I'll be finding use for that manner of targeting a key within a key :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I had to try it out myself, so it's good to know for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you set a nested object in localStorage like that

```
const dataObj = {
    uid: {
        name: 'robin',
        age: 24,
    }

} 

window.localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(dataObj));
```

Now you want to delete the `age` property. You can't remove it with `removeItem` native function since it allows to delete from top level.

So you need to get the data first and delete the property you want and set the data again to localStorage with updated value like that

```
const existingLocalStorage = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('users') || {});
if(existingLocalStorage['uid']['age']) { // if throws any error, use lodash get fucntion for getting value
    delete existingLocalStorage['uid']['age'];
}
window.localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(existingLocalStorage));
```